# Community Wiki and FAQs

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, self-answer, canonical-questions

If I have a FAQ or some little known information should I phrase my question as a FAQ instead of a question when posting on Stack Overflow or is this type of post frowned upon?

Comment: Are you talking about programming information or Stack Overflow information?

Comment: Could you explain how a question and a FAQ would differ in your case?

Comment: IT would essentially be information regarding parsing MP4 files. More than what atomicparsley offers. I would include things like tips when accessing the file in different languages and general file information as well as some gotcha's I have learned about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write it in the form of a question, then answer it yourself after a day.

Comment: I'll give that a shot

Comment: @DeanMc: And no need to answer it yourself if someone else says essentially what you would answer.  Accepting a self-answer with nearly identical content is frowned upon by most.  (But posting your answer and accept someone else's nearly-identical answer would be fine.)

Comment: I'l Keep that in mind.